# Querying maximum socket send buffer size in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I know I can cat  /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max to get the maximum size for SO_SNDBUF on a socket, but is there an easy way to query that value in C without going through the kludgy-feeling steps of opening the file, reading, and converting to an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of the net.ipv4.tcp_wmem sysctl, you need to parse it out of the /proc file representing that sysctl (there really is no better way on Linux, and the sysctl system call has long since been deprecated.)

Something like:

```
unsigned long wmem_min,wmem_default,wmem_max;
FILE *f = fopen("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem", "r");
if(f == NULL)
   fail();
if(fscanf(f, "%lu %lu %lu", &wmem_min,&wmem_default,&wmem_max) != 3)
  fail();

fclose(f);
 ... use wmem_max
```

For a particular socket, you can get the current remaining buffer with

```
  socklen_t optlen;
  int send_buf, rc;
  optlen = sizeof(send_buf);
  //if getsockopt is successful, send_buf will hold the buffer size
  rc = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &send_buf, &optlen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you invoke the **sysctl** command on the shell (use **system()** or **popen/pclose()**) to get this information...at least avoids opening a file but may be equivalent in overall ugliness:

```
system("sysctl -n net.ipv4.tcp_wmem");
```

Comment: Ha! Ha! When you run another command you `fork()`, prepare an `execve()` (i.e. break up the command/arguments as separate strings), `open()` & `read()` that command file (`/sbin/sysctl` here) then you load all the dependencies (i.e. the `.so` libraries) and with `popen()` you also create a FIFO to communicate between your two processes. Definitely excessive!