# Best way to send large arrays of integers over TCP sockets?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I am not asking for any specific code, but I would like some direction since I'm new to sockets in C++.  I was wondering what is the best way to send large data sets of integers?  I know there is a buffer limit on how much is being sent so obviously you cannot send a huge array.  How does this work then?  Do you make multiple send calls with smaller arrays?  If so, how do you know how small each chunk should be?  I need to be able to send large data sets with integers in the millions, so I would appreciate some sort of advice or explanation as to how this would work with TCP sockets in C++.  Thanks!

Comment: c or c++ ? both are tagged.

Comment: Well you sure as hell can't send 6496043689540649646464 bytes of integers in one send call.

Comment: @Robert but you can't even keep them in RAM, so...

Comment: So you are saying I can't send large data sets of integers then...?  No one is being constructive here.

Comment: TCP has got his own buffers, but as long as you are using blocking calls, the library should be able to handle arrays of any size. For more details, you should specify which library you are using, as C and C++ do not define a standard socket API

Comment: I'm using these if this answers your question
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

Comment: Of course, if your data can't fit in RAM, you can't use a single big array, but will have to sample your data. Anyway, to answer your question, in order to hide network latencies and overhead, you should send chunks as big as you can. Things change if you want to be fault-tolerant. Then, smaller chunks are lighter to reply if transmission fails, and then you have to make a tradeoff.

Comment: How big can these chunks be?  Is there a certain maximum number of bytes?

Comment: Check the good article here http://www.onlamp.com/2005/11/17/tcp_tuning.html

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980620/querying-maximum-socket-send-buffer-size-in-c
It's about 200KB on my PC, but it can vary. I think 32KB is reasonable, as some C compilers even fail to create arrays larger than that.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: With TCP, the user doesn't (normally) have to worry about the fault-tolerance. The TCP stack will accumulate smaller pieces to create a larger packet, and will split large packets into reasonable-sized transmission units.

Comment: @JerryCoffin if the host disconnects for 30 seconds, your trasmission will fail with a "host unreachable" error, and you will have to handle it manually. TCP is fault-tolerant with respect to network congestion and packet loss, but it fails if the host is unreachable for too long. When I said fault-tolerant, I was speaking of something like resumable download, when the endpoint might go down anytime and resume the transfer minutes or even days later.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Some good comments there, but 'smaller chunks are lighter to reply to if transmission fails' isn't one of them. An ACK is an ACK, it doesn't matter how large the chunk is, and TCP doesn't require that an entire chunk be retransmitted, only the missing bytes.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: Yes, if you want to resume after a connection is dropped, you have to handle that separately, *but* it's generally pretty much independent of the size of "chunk" you transmit.

Comment: @JerryCoffin When a transmission fails (because the host disappears), you have to resend the last non-completed chunk. The bigger the chunks are, the more you have to retransmit. At the limit, if the whole array is a single chunk, you have to resend it from scratch. On the other side, if you use 1B chunks, you can stop&resume transfers with a resolution of 1B (you never send the same byte twice), but you drown in overhead. Anyway, I feel we're getting off-topic here.

Comment: @GiulioFranco A successful `send()` doesn't mean the peer received the data or that it has even been transmitted yet, and, since TCP is stream-oriented, the receiver might get data from `recv()` before you finished sending.  It's up to the receiver to mark completion, not the sender.